# Java.net missing classes?

Tags: java

I downloaded Oracle's java7 sdk from repository: ppa:webupd8team/java and
I run ubuntu 12.04.

When i use sockets etc and other classes from java.net its fine.

But when i search for:

```
import java.net.SocketOption;
import java.net.StandardSocketOptions;
import java.nio.channels.NetworkChannel;
```

I cannot find a thing. It says it cannot find the symbol. Do i have to install something more? Is it something that i have to do to work with these classes?

Comment: Is this an IDE problem or does it also not run from the terminal ? Could you check this ?

Comment: why don't you download sdk from official webpage?

Comment: @fuubah Checked. Its not compiling either from terminal.

Comment: Clearly the JDK used is older than Java 7 then. I believe you that you installed Java 7, but that doesn't necessarily mean you are compiling stuff with it.

Comment: @bigdestroyer Do i have to remove the current sdk first?

Comment: @Gimby but java version (java -version) shows: 
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: I had java 6, and i installed java 7, and used: update-alternatives --config java, to set the default to be java 7

Comment: Download sdk from official webpage may be the best way. Once downloaded, you just have to change JAVA_HOME env var to the new sdk path and change the sdk configuration in your IDE. You don't have to remove your current sdk, but it won't be util.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. 
I installed OpenJDK from the ubuntu's repository.

Then i switched the default to be OpenJDK:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that classes' source code in src.zip, directly in the JDKs root folder.

Comment: There are in my root JDK's root folder too, in src.zip. What shall i do?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: IDE is Geany. The problem was that the repository was old enough or it was messy. I installed OpenJDK and everything is fine now. Thanks